# Error en Whiles anidados PHP consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos consultas las cuales quiero restar entre ellas

```
$query_pml = "SELECT 
                    fecha, 
                    hora, 
                    fechahora, 
                    pml_mda 
                    FROM 
                    `$tabla` 
                    WHERE $zona_carga='$zona' 
                    $solar
                    and 
                    fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' 
                    order by fecha, $identificador asc;";
     
$query_pml_mtr = "SELECT 
                fecha, 
                hora, 
                fechahora, 
                pml_mtr 
                FROM 
                `$tabla_mtr` 
                WHERE $zona_carga='$zona' 
                $solar
                and 
                fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' 
                order by fecha, $identificador asc;";
```

De estas dos consultas hago el while

```
$fire = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query_pml);
$fire2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_pml_mtr);
$pml_mda = array();                                                             
$pml_mtr = array();
     while ($rorigen=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
         $pml_mda = $rorigen['pml_mda']/$moneda;
            while ($rdestino = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire2)) {
                $pml_mtr = $rdestino['pml_mtr']/$moneda;
                $diferencia =$pml_mda-$pml_mtr;
                echo $diferencia.",";
            }
     }
```

El problema que tengo es que el resultado el primer while no conserva los datos solo repite el primer valor a lo largo del arreglo. en cambio el segundo arreglo si conserva sus datos correctamente.
Hice un query donde me busca estos datos pero tarda casi 20 segundos en ejecutarse solo esa consulta.

```
$query="SELECT a.fecha as fecha, a.hora as hora, a.pml_mda as pml_mda,
    b.pml_mtr as pml_mtr, TRUNCATE((a.pml_mda-b.pml_mtr),2) as dart
FROM $tabla a
LEFT JOIN $tabla_mtr b
    ON a.fecha = b.fecha AND a.hora = b.hora
WHERE a.$zona_carga = b.$zona_carga
    AND a.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin'
    AND a.$zona_carga = '$zona' 
GROUP BY a.fecha, a.$identificador
ORDER BY a.fecha, a.$identificador";
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Por eso opte en realizar la resta en PHP el cual es mas rapido. Ojala puedan orientarme

Comment: Puedes probar guardarlo como un arreglo, esta línea: ```$pml_mda[] = $rorigen['pml_mda']/$moneda;``` de esa forma no se sobrescribe, luego puedes crear un contador asociativo en tu otra while para acceder a su valor, algo como ```$pml_mda[$contador]-$pml_mtr```.

Comment: Disculpa la demora anoche termine muy tarde otro proyecto. Lo probare aun que no me queda muy claro lo de =$contador, soy muy nuevo en esto disculpame podrias ampliar tu respuesta un poco mas si es posible? gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como estas pasando esta línea `$pml_mda = $rorigen['pml_mda']/$moneda;` siempre te va pasar el valor del primer registro.

Un posibilidad es guardarlo en un array, algo como: `$pml_mda[] = $rorigen['pml_mda'] / $moneda;`

En sí, tienes que cambiar un poco la lógica.

**Te dejo cambios**

```
// Reseteas 
$pml_mda = $pml_mtr = [];
// Obtienes datos fire 1
while ($rorigen=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) $pml_mda[] = $rorigen['pml_mda'] / $moneda;
// Obtienes datos fire 2
while ($rdestino = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire2)) $pml_mtr[] = $rdestino['pml_mtr'] / $moneda;

// Calculas
// es importante que obtengas los mismos registros de las dos sentencias, ya que sino el calculo te va fallar.            
foreach ($pml_mda as $clave => $valor) {
    // Obtienes el valor de pml_mtr accediendo por clave
    $diferencia = $valor - $pml_mtr[$clave];
    echo $diferencia.",";
}
```

**Alternativa**

Personalmente crearía una sola sentencia, dices que calculando se te demora 20 segundos, pues intenta obtener solo los datos relacionados con **LEFT JOIN** como lo estás haciendo y luego ya en PHP calculas el valor deseado.

La parte **ON** cambia la a tus necesidades

```
ON    
    a.fecha = b.fecha AND 
    a.hora = b.hora AND
    a.$zona_carga = b.$zona_carga
```

o

```
ON    
    a.fecha = b.fecha AND 
    a.hora = b.hora
```

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
$query = "SELECT 
                        a.fecha, 
                        a.hora, 
                        a.fechahora, 
                        a.pml_mda,
                        b.fecha as `mtr_fecha`,
                        b.hora as `mtr_hora`,
                        b.fechahora as `mtr_fechahora`,
                        b.pml_mtr 
                FROM 
                        $tabla AS a
           LEFT JOIN    
                        $tabla_mtr AS b 
                  ON    
                        a.fecha = b.fecha AND 
                        a.hora = b.hora AND
                        /* a.$zona_carga = b.$zona_carga */
               WHERE 
                        a.$zona_carga = '$zona' 
                        $solar AND
                        a.fecha between '$fecha_ini' and '$fecha_fin' 
            ORDER BY    
                        a.fecha, a.$identificador 
                 ASC
";
// Ejecutas sentencia
$sentencia = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

// Obtienes datos
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sentencia)) {
    // Obtienes pml_mda   
    $pml_mda = $resultado['pml_mda'] / $moneda;
    // Obtienes pml_mtr
    $pml_mtr = $resultado['pml_mtr'] / $moneda;  

    // Restas valores
    $diferencia =$pml_mda - $pml_mtr;  

    // Salida
    echo "$diferencia, ";            
}
```

**Edit:**

Para que entiendas la lógica de la opción 1.

```
$pml_mda = $hora_mda = [];

while ($rorigen=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    $pml_mda[]  = $rorigen['pml_mda'] / $moneda;
    $hora_mda[] = $rorigen['hora'];
}
```

Supongamos que tengas solo 7 registros.
Entonces con la línea de arriba obtienes algo como esto:
**$pml_mda:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 85
    [5] => 55
    [6] => 1
)
```

**$hora_mda:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20.00
    [1] => 08.21
    [2] => 11.28
    [3] => 23.45
    [4] => 21.00
    [5] => 15.58
    [6] => 17.13
)
```

Lo misma pasa con **$pml_mtr[]**, entonces las claves coinciden siempre que haya mismo registros en las dos tablas.

En el foreach simplemente para obtener la hora haces esto:

```
foreach ($pml_mda as $clave => $valor) {
    // Otro valor de tabla 1 (su hora)
    echo 'Hora: ' . $hora_mda[$clave] . '<br>';
    // Obtienes el valor de pml_mtr accediendo por clave
    $diferencia = $valor - $pml_mtr[$clave];
    echo $diferencia.",";
}
```

Piensa que al recorrer con el foreach $clave = 0; y si va incrementando por cada registro, por eso coinciden.

Prueba `echo 'Clave= ' . $clave . '<br>';` y lo veras.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha quedado muy clara tu explicacion me fui por el segundo metodo se me hizo mas confiable de nuevo gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo, me alegro, un saludo.

Comment: una duda en el primer ejemplo a demas de traer el pml quisiera traer la hora y la fecha para poder hacer una tabla? que tendria que modificar.

Comment: Solo agregue esos campos en el 2do while y funciono. 
while ($rdestino = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
 $pml_mtr[] = $rdestino['pml_mtr'] / $moneda;
 $fecha[] = $rdestino['fecha'];
 $hora[] = $rdestino['hora'];
}          
foreach ($pml_mda as $clave => $valor) {
  $fecha_tabla = $fecha[$clave];
  $hora_tabla = $hora[$clave];
     $diferencia = $valor - $pml_mtr[$clave];
     $dart= $diferencia.",";
}

Comment: @JoaquinDuran me alegro amigo, simplemente si eliges la opción 1, es como mencionas lo añades a tu sentencia las columnas que deseas añadir y después haces el mismo proceso por cada columna :)

Comment: tengo una duda, ejemplo quiero sacar de la primera consulta mas valores como lo puedo hacer?? ya lo he estado intentando y no me deja solo he podido sacar del segundo

Comment: Lo podrías hacer de la misma manera, añades otro array con el valor deseado, por ejemplo:```while ($rorigen=..{``` añades ```$hora_mda[] = $rorigen['hora'] ;```  y en el **foreach()** haces  ```echo $hora_mda[$clave] . '<br>'; ``` ¿el segundo ejemplo no te funciono?

Comment: Si me funciono pero tarda mucho y me da error 504 getway, las tablas son muy pesadas. en el primer caso es mas rapido

Comment: lo solucione como tu me muestras mil gracias, otra duda diras que soy muy tonto pero el resultado $diferencia; he tratado de sacar el valor maximo.
 $array = explode ( ' ', $diferencia );
echo max($array); pero no me trae el valor maximo me trae el array completo.

Comment: Te he dejado un apartado **Edit** para que entiendas mejor la lógica del ejemplo 1. Normalmente se hace con ```max()```, https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php, quizás añadiendo la coma **,** ```$array = explode ( ',', $diferencia );```, puedes mirar también haciendo ```var_dump($array);``` y vez como está formado etc. y si no puedes abrir una nueva pregunta al respecto, no es pregunta tonta. Un saludo amigo.